# Rails 4 - Comparing two variables in scope

Tags: ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

How do you compare two variables in a custom scope with Rails 4 ?

Documentation and common examples always show basic comparisons with table attributes

Like in this example :

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :created_before, ->(time) { where("created_at < ?", time) }
end
```

But in my case, I want to compare a datetime from my Model to a date string coming from a form submission

```
scope :departure, -> (departure) { where("departure = ?", "%#{departure}%")}
```

The problem is that I want to do some manipulation to my model variable before the comparison (ex, convert to string or change format)

I tried with different methods like this one

```
def self.departure(departure)
  @date_without_time = flights.departure.to_date.to_s
  where(@date_without_time, "= ?", departure)
end
```

But the condition end up like this (2012-01-03) instead of (departure = "%#{departure}%")

Is there a better way to do it?
To be more general, how do you create methods or scope to compare two variables instead of only comparing one variable to a model attribute?

In this case, I want to compare my model attribute which is a Datetime with a form submitted string date, so before I can compare the two dates I need to do some treatment on my model attribute since I need to ignore the time part and format it to a string

**Update :**

I ended up making it work using this method, but I'd still like to know if it's possible to call class or instance method on a Model column in a scope or if there is a better way to handle the Datetime/form date comparison in a better way

```
scope :departure_s, -> (departure) { where("departure > ?", departure.to_datetime.beginning_of_day)}
scope :departure_e, -> (departure) { where("departure < ?", departure.to_datetime.end_of_day)}
scope :departure, -> (departure) {  departure_e(departure).departure_s(departure)}
```

Comment: Why can't you use `"%#{departure}%"` instead of `departure` in the seconds case as well?

Comment: do you want pattern mataching search or simple comparisons? Looking at your code `%..%`, you want to use `like`..

Comment: I only wanted to show a simple example of why my self.departure method didn't work, I edited the question for the example to match the initial problem. I want to find object where my model Datetime variable is equals to a string date submitted from a form, so I need to do some treatments on my model variable since I need to ignore the time and format it to a string before I can compare and that's why a simple scope comparison doesn't work

Comment: `scope :departure, -> (departure) { where(departure: departure.to_datetime.beginning_of_day..depature.to_datetime.end_of_day)` seems like a more suitable option to match `date` to `datetime`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're taking the wrong approach trying to manipulate models. You're running a query to return models, you don't have any models to manipulate yet.

You can accomplish what you're trying to do on the database level with SQL. I would write the scope like this

if the departure variable is a string that represents a date in the format 'yyyy-mm-dd' you can do

```
scope :departure, -> (departure) { where("date(departure) = ?", departure )}
```

This assumes you're using postgres, it might be slightly  different for mysql. the date() function converts a datetime to date on the database elevel

Comment: It worked with slight modification for MySQL, thanks